# According to this function, can y = 8?

Tags: multithreading, assembly

```
int y = 0;  // global

void ThreadFunc(int &y){  // local reference var that shadows the global
  y += 2;
}
```

If this is being run from 5 threads,  can y = 8? If so, what would this look like in assembly language that would lead y = 8?

Comment: This sounds like a homework question; what are your thoughts?

Comment: Actually, wouldnt multiple threads push and pop into a race condition making it unsafe?

Comment: I mean, the whole thing is a big race condition (and thus undefined behavior at the level of the C++ language).  I'm not sure what you mean by "push and pop"; each thread will have its own stack so there's no conflict there.

Comment: In C++, yes, for plain `int y` (not `std::atomic<int>`), it would be Undefined Behaviour for multiple unsynchronized threads to write `y`.   See [Can num++ be atomic for 'int num'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39393850) for C++ vs. asm.  Actually that has answers which explain the asm / cpu-architecture details of non-atomic increments stepping on each other. Also, are they all supposed to be called with their arg referring to the global `y`?  Why bother having an arg at all?  Seems like it would be a better example with ThreadFunc directly accessing the global.